# Not able to call etag in put request in node js

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am trying to call external API using Node and AngularJS as a front end. My requirement is to pass Etag header parameter through put request to external API. I am not able to pass Etag parameter from headers. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

I have tried below code to pass through put request but still I have not reached a solution.

```
 'If-Match': function(config) {
        return config.data.version;
      }
```

Node API:

```
router.put('/node1Api', function(req, res){

  request.put(
    {
    url:'Example.com',
    json: {
      "caseTypeID": "EAIS-UCEF-Work-ComplaintProcess",

      "content": { 

        "ComplaintReason" : req.body.ComplaintReason,
        "ComplaintDescription" : req.body.ComplaintDescription,

        }
         },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'If-Match': function(config) {
        return config.data.version;
      }
    }
    },
  function(error, response, body){

    console.log(body);
     res.send(body);
})
  });
```

I want to pass that If-Match Tag as a header parameter. I want to match this Etag (If-Match) header parameter with external API so that we get success response and our details get updated in that subsequent case.

Comment: You should pass the actual value for the `if-match`-header instead of a function.

Comment: Yes, i have tried that also but not able to update details. I want to dynamically pass that ETAG through headers.